# How is a method getting is called by an instance of its abstract class. I've attached the github issue

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, dependency-inversion

How is the method being called since the `NumberTriviaRepository` that is imported is just an abstract class whose implementation is in a completely different file as in the attached issue

Please refer: https://github.com/arc-arnob/clean_code_architecture_tdd_bloc/issues/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. The connection between the abstract class and the concrete implementation is made by dependency injection. Let me give you a brief explanation of my understanding of this code flow. I hope it will clear up your confusion.
If you look at the `injection_container.dart` file, you will see that `NumberTriviaRepository` is registered there and injected with the implementation.

#### injection_container.dart

```dart
  //! Repository
  sl.registerLazySingleton<NumberTriviaRepository>(
    () => NumberTriviaRepositoryImplementation(
      localDataSource: sl(),
      networkInfo: sl(),
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
    ),
  );
```

So when the `GetConcreteNumberTrivia` use case is invoked as it is also registered in `injection_container.dart` as a singleton, it creates a new instance if it doesn't exist or provides a previous instance.

While creating that instance, it notices that it needs to inject `NumberTriviaRepository`. As it is also registered in `injection_container.dart`, it returns `NumberTriviaRepositoryImplementation` according to the instruction.

That's how we can use the `repository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(params.number)` function, and the repository we are receiving in the constructor of the `GetConcreteNumberTrivia` class is the instance that we created in the injection file.
I hope it helps you to understand this topic.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, was very helpful! I've unknowingly used constructor injection here and rather than creating a `NumberTriviaRepository` object inside the class, the class's constructor takes a `NumberTriviaRepository` object as a parameter and assigns it to a repository property.